# what is the reason for "wrong predecessor" when endorsing

Tags: endorser, missed-endorsement

My endorser just missed an endorsement slot with the following error:

```
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement: Error while injecting endorsement for delegate <redacted> :
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:   Error:
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:     Unregistred error:
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:       { "kind": "generic",
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:         "error":
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:           "Error while applying operation <redacted>:\nbranch delayed (Error:\n                  Wrong predecessor <redacted>, expected <redacted>\n)" }
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:
Apr 28 08:11:08 - client.endorsement:
```

Can anyone explain what does this mean and is there anything I should do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you try to inject an endorsement in your mempool for a block that wasn't the head block. Maybe the chain reorganized between the time your endorser started preparing an endorsement and the time it was injected. This can happen but it should be very rare.

Comment: Just happened to us between 521695 and 521696. Any way to prevent this? https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/555

Comment: Also just happened to us as well https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/missed-endorsement-unregistred-error