# Missed endorsement - unregistred error

Tags: baking, endorsement

I missed an endorsement but only one. Afterwards - all back to normal. Error message was

Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement: Error while injecting endorsement for delegate : XXX
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement:   Error:
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement:     Unregistred error:
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement:       { "kind": "generic",
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement:         "error":
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement:           "Error while applying operation XXX:\nbranch delayed (Error:\n                  Wrong predecessor XXXY, expected XXXXYX\n)" }
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement: 
Aug 22 00:22:38 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.endorsement:

Comment: Apparently, a similar question was already asked here: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/1149/409 and answered by Arthur. "This should be very rare". But no actual fix.